# merging data bt tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, merge, union

I have three tables with the following structure:

```
tb1: id(AI, PK), uid, date, text
tb2: id(AI, PK), uid, date, text ... and so on
```

I have to keep them separate because of additional unqiue data that each table has.
I'd like to execute a query that will merge and get me the last 20 entries (ie, `date DESC`) (specifically, i need `uid` and `text`)
from all 3 tables combined (as if this was one big table).

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  uid, text
        FROM    tb1
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        LIMIT 20
        ) q
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  uid, text
        FROM    tb2
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        LIMIT 20
        ) q2
UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT  uid, text
        FROM    tb3
        ORDER BY
                date DESC
        LIMIT 20
        ) q3
ORDER BY
        date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This is more efficient than a mere `UNION ALL`.

See this article in my blog for performance comparison:

- [**`MySQL`: `LIMIT` on `LIMIT`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/05/mysql-limit-on-limit/)